# Nodejs use framework or not

Tags: node.js, lambda

I am about to start writing the server component for a client app.  This will primarily be using nodejs and a nosql db.  Furthermore this should be deployable on AWS Lambda.  Since I am fairly new to this can someone please provide me with the following information

1. Should/Can I use any other third party framework like Meteor or should I write everything from scratch?
2. From where should I start, is there a reference project that I can use for reference when using something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is designed to work best for single-purpose functions and apps. So you want to use something more lightweight.

1. Because Meteor uses websockets to communicate between server and client, it needs the server to remain running, which is incompatible with the Lambda model. Something less comprehensive, like express / koa / etc would suit better here.
2. Take a look [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) and other systems designed for cloud functions

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question when I first started writing Lambda Functions.

I have been developing REST API's using the AWS Serverless Stack (API Gateway, Lambda, and DynamoDB) and writing request validations and some business logic started to be repetitive and some times painful (especially if you're using API Gateway Proxy Integration).

So,

> 1. Should/Can I use any other third party framework like Meteor or should I write everything from scratch?

You can use a framework. But first, try to write from scratch, See if you can be productive without any framework. A Lambda Function should do one thing, so I can't see something really complex here.

I found myself writing a [micro framework(aws-wave)](https://github.com/it-gorillaz/aws-wave) because all the time I had to:

- Handle Exception - If you're using API Gateway and you don't handle exceptions properly, you'll get **Bad Gateway** responses;
- Request Validation - Repeating validation code started to be boring.
- Formating the Response - In my case I had to format the response as API Gateway expects.

There's also an [awesome serverless list](https://github.com/anaibol/awesome-serverless) with a lot of tools that may help you.

> 2. From where should I start, is there a reference project that I can use for reference when using something like this?

I agree with the previous answer, take a look at [Serverless](https://serverless.com/)